# How can I get the names of the columns in an object or table with Joomla's SQL?

Tags: database, jdatabase, sql

With the existing output I have from a basic query, what would be the best way to get the names of the columns in the resultant output object without having to run an additional COLUMNS query on the database - in order to save database calls?

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__table');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    ----

    foreach($results as $key=>$value)
    {
       echo $key;
    }
```

It returns an object, but none of my attempts to get the key from key => value seem to be working, even with a foreach loop. I don't want to run extra queries just to get my keys. How would I do this with the existing output from $results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `foreach` will result in situation where $key is array key and $value is one row from database. If you want to get column names from result just use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__table');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

// this will return array of object properties
// in format: array('column1'=>'content1','column2'=>'content2')
$properties = get_object_vars($results[0]);
```

You can also just ask for array of arrays instead of array of objects. Its made like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__table');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadAssocList();

// this will return array of column names properties
// in format: array('column1','column2')
$columns = array_keys($results[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was that trailing [0] I've been missing on the array_keys version, I've tried it a couple attempts but never got it right.

Comment: If you use IDE add Joomla `/libraries` directory to includes. That way you will know what certain function return.

Answer (score 3):

To get all columns of a table as arrays use JDatabase class method as follows:

```
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$columnArr=$db->getTableColumns("#__table_name");
foreach ($columnArr as $key => $value) {
    // here $key will be column name and $value will be type
    // process array code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$columns = $db->getTableKeys('tableName');
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but I don't think that the method takes an array: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/840955ff8668f0b845b456df99fe1326e34b14dd/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php#L465

Comment: You are right, I was looking at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/840955ff8668f0b845b456df99fe1326e34b14dd/libraries/joomla/database/driver.php#L1229 which suggests that it should take an array..but implementation is inconsistent with that

Comment: This is a handy method, but it does not satisfy the question requirements.  The OP wants the column names and the data in a single query.  Your single query only delivers half of the required data.